# '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

Im getting this error when my SignUp View returns the reverse_lazy function:

```
AttributeError at /signup/
'__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My view:

```
class SignUpView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context = {'form':UserCreateForm})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'request: {request.POST}')

        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit = False)
            user.username = request.POST.get('email')
            user.save()

            return reverse_lazy('homePage')
```

The form:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta():
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'departments', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = get_user_model()
```

User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

What is causing the error?

Edit - (Error traceback)

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/signup/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.7.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts',
 'counts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ricardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Ricardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Ricardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /signup/
Exception Value: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I'm just typing some text to break the "
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." rule

Comment: Please add the full error stacktrace, because there it says which line is causing the error.

Comment: This is not your ***complete error traceback*** though

Comment: Please check my edit, added the traceback.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, stackoverflow doesn't let me post more than this.. I migth try a screenshot

Comment: Just switch to "copy-paste" mode. You will understand how to do it

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, done, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this is because you are not returning an HTTP response from your view.

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse


class SignUpView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context={'form': UserCreateForm})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'request: {request.POST}')

        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = request.POST.get('email')
            user.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('homePage'))
        return HttpResponse('Form not valid')
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Somehow i thought that reverse would give a response object..

Comment: reverse actually returns a string.